# xCode 6 autoLayout doesn't automatically resize

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I'm loading a nib I have created using the new autolayout system (600px X 600px) (ANY to ANY).

For some reason, this specific viewController is not autoresizing to the boundaries of my phone. After it loads it is still 600 X 600.

What could it be?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that this viewcontroller is supposed to float above everything else... Like an alert message.

This is the function that I use to call it:

```
+ (void)showFiltersWithDelegate:(id<FiltersViewControllerDelegate>)delegator {
    weakSelf = [[self alloc] initWithNibName:@"FiltersViewController" bundle:nil];
    weakSelf.delegate = delegator;
    [weakSelf initDataOjects];
    [weakSelf animateIn];
    [weakSelf animateCancelButton];
}
```

Comment: why cannot you set the default iphone size and try to check for autoresize.why are you trying for 600 *600

Comment: give freeform view size in xib